# PTIJ: whats the diffrence

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Whits teh difference btween arur hAman and Baruch mosses?

--

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/)

Comment: I resent that this question has two downvotes.

Comment: They missed the upvote button (and why!)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

OK. You have had enough. Consider the mitzvah fulfilled.

Answer (score 15):

In a bed. Stuff that grows by more than half (Rama :29 and Aruch Hashulchan there) do not say to say "Ma tovu". Aruch Hashulchan 695:18 writes: ויש להסתפק אם שלח לקטן אם יצא ונראה לעניות דעתי שיצא דהא לרעהו כתיב וגם קטן חייב׃ One can be in doubt as to whether, if one sent [mishloach manos] to a minor, he knows [the difference] between "cursed is in the case of an interruption is forbidden if it occupies one mind, taking it away from the sale remain intact but the buyer did it on purpose, I see does he (or Mishna B'rura) discuss a non-Jew as mishloach manos recipient. As far as the m'lacha of Shabbos by Rabbi Simcha Bunim Cohen) as saying that, even if one plans to extend his meal that he has escaped [it], for "to his friend" is written and even Ashk'nazim, don't rely on the exception.

Halacha book Ben Ish Chay (year 2, 115:2). (They allow it because one says before mincha (MB 234:6–7; AHS 237:1–2). It's a machlokes amoraim. As far as the m'lacha of cooking goes, it's fine as far as wheat needs merits, specifically the merit of the מצוה of חלה; thus, according to תוספות, even though one mind, taking it away from the prohibition on a man and girl's seclusion may start later and that, although he doesn't wish to permit doing so. (Orach Chayim 3 #42.) The first משנה of מסכת פיצה reads: פיצה שנולדה ביום טוב בית שמאי אומרים תאכל ובית הלל אומרים זה וזה בכזית.‏ Pizza that came in contact with a dead sheretz (small animal, let's say): the keli before sunset is that it can invalidate t'ruma by touching it. (We ask that he have mercy on one arm and a hat in Lev. 22, telling us that it, too,.

h/t [Flack Overstow](https://quickmediasolutions.com/flack)

Answer (score 7):

It's been four years since I originally posted this question, and I've learned a lot in that time. Obviously the "difference" between two words or phrases is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) from one to the other. The Levenshtein distance between "arur haman" and "baruch mosses" is 9, so that is the difference between them.

Comment: wow, you've really sobered up