# Artificial Intelligence writing Divrei Torah

Tags: technology, artificial-lifeform

There have been a number of artificial intelligence machine learning systems over the last few years which have been given samples of artwork and music and have produced new creative works.  I haven't come across any systems that have done the same with literature yet, but I am guessing it is only a matter of time before we have a machine generated murder mystery.

I was thinking it would be interesting to feed a similar system sample Divrei Torah and see what it could produce.  Hypothetically it could be connected up to Sefaria and similar data sources for drawing on pesukim etc as textual sources to base the Dvar on.  This does raise some interesting questions though.  Is there any reason that such a project would present problems from the perspective of halacha (or perhaps hashkafa etc)?  Would any results produced from the system be necessarily inherently problematic (eg. as long as a sufficiently qualified human reviews it to ensure there is nothing that would be problematic if a human wrote it)?

Comment: [It already exists](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/36372/1569). It got a +15 score, so apparently it's acceptable

Comment: @ba Haha!  That's pretty cool, but I was thinking of something a bit more general than answering Mi Yodeya questions.

Comment: https://openai.com/blog/better-language-models/

Comment: In seriousness, I don't really understand what the problems this presents could be. If you already have a human reviewing it, what inherent problem is there with something being AI-generated? Human-generated Torah isn't flawless either, is it?

Comment: Technically, nothing is Divrey Torah until accepted as such. Surely Gogle can write a summary on any subject incl. Torah or Halachah. Eventually, passing the Turing Test, I don't think anybody could distinguish it from human work. Eventually, it will pass Rabbis in its clarity, consistency, and scope of sources. Maybe we will call it מלאה הארץ דעה את ה' as the Navi prophecized?

Comment: לא ניתנה התורה למלאכי השרת ולא לבינה מלאכותית

Comment: Generative AI are word machines, not understanding or logic machines. Therefore you can't classify something an AI wrote as Torah, since there is no understanding inherent in its generation.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Is it necessary for there to have been understanding inherent in its generation for it to be Torah?  If it is indistinguishable from a human-written Dvar Torah, maybe the act of reading it makes it Torah?

Comment: @MosesSupposes But then if a monkey would type out a *dvar torah* you could say the same thing?

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Yes, so? To my mind the only difference is that is far less likely statistically.

Comment: @MosesSupposes So it's not Torah.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Does it matter how it was derived as long as it works as a dvar torah?

Comment: @MosesSupposes A monkey cannot comprise a connection to Hashem.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE But if a monkey writes something that inspires someone else to enhance their connection to Hashem then is that a Dvar Torah?  Is it the source or the effect that matters?

Comment: @MosesSupposes That's not possible.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE certainly statistically unlikely but it is much more likely for an AI